# I don't understand why my loop is missing numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

Output shows that the numbers 13 is misplaced and 19 is completely missing, I apologize in advance for the inadequateness of the post, my first question here.

```
 fav_num = {
       'john': [18, 23, 30],
       'serena': [12, 7],
       'bryan': [13],
       'james': [19],
       'ashley': [10, 13],
    }

for name, numbers in fav_num.items():


        if len(numbers) >= 2:
            print(f"{name.title()} favorite numbers are:")

        else:
            print(f"{name.title()} favorite number is {number}.\n")

        for number in numbers:

    
            if len(numbers) >= 2:
                print(f"\t{number}")
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hint: look at the line "favorite number is {number}", and trace backwards to where "number" can come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: you use `print(f"{name.title()} favorite number is {number}.\n")`  and number use the `number` in the previous one.

change to : `print(f"{name.title()} favorite number is {numbers[0]}.\n")`

see below full code

```
fav_num = {
           'john': [18, 23, 30],
           'serena': [12, 7],
           'bryan': [13],
           'james': [19],
           'ashley': [10, 13],
        }
    
    for name, numbers in fav_num.items():
            if len(numbers) >= 2:
                print(f"{name.title()} favorite numbers are:")
            else:
                print(f"{name.title()} favorite number is {numbers[0]}.\n")
            for number in numbers:  
                if len(numbers) >= 2:
                    print(f"\t{number}")
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to point out here. Importantly, in the else statement you immediately reference a *number*. However, in the iterator of the for loop you do not have access to this number. You can check this by trying to insert a person with only 1 number to the front of your fav_num list and the program should crash correspondingly. The reason that it's been working unexpectedly, is due to the presence of a *number* variable that is a remnant from the previous iteration of the for loop. Try and reason through each step of the for loop given this information and argue why this results in the 7 showing up at Bryan, and the 13 showing up at James.  Instead, within your else statement, you may wish to index the first number of the *numbers* list (given that you're always sure it has at least 1 entry).